# Why use push/pop instead of sub and mov?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

When I play around with different compilers on https://godbolt.org, I notice that it's very common for compilers to generate code like this:

```
push    rax
push    rbx
push    rcx
call    rdx
pop     rcx
pop     rbx
pop     rax
```

I understand that each `push` or `pop` does two things:

1. move the operand to/from the stack space
2. increment/decrement the stack pointer (rsp)

So in our example above, I assume the CPU is actually doing 12 operations (6 moves, 6 adds/subs), not including the `call`. Wouldn't it be more efficient to combine the adds/subs? For example:

```
sub rsp, 24
mov [rsp-24], rax
mov [rsp-16], rbx
mov [rsp-8], rcx
call    rdx
mov rcx, [rsp-8]
mov rbx, [rsp-16]
mov rax, [rsp-24]
add rsp, 24
```

Now there are only 8 operations (6 moves, 2 adds/subs), not including the `call`. Why do compilers not use this approach?

Comment: what is the size of each instruction?  how many bytes to do the push/pop, how many bytes to do register offset addressing?  consider xor rax,rax vs mov rax,0 as an example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you compile with `-mtune=pentium3` or something earlier than `-mtune=pentium-m`, GCC *will* do code-gen like you imagined, because on those old CPUs push/pop really does decode to a separate ALU operation on the stack pointer as well as a load/store.  (You'll have to use `-m32`, or `-march=nocona` (64-bit P4 Prescott) because those old CPUs also don't support x86-64).  [Why does gcc use movl instead of push to pass function args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534791/why-does-gcc-use-movl-instead-of-push-to-pass-function-args?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But Pentium-M introduced a "stack engine" in the front-end that eliminates the stack-adjustment part of stack ops like push/call/ret/pop.  It effectively renames the stack pointer with zero latency.  See [Agner Fog's microarch guide](https://agner.org/optimize/) and [What is the stack engine in the Sandybridge microarchitecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture)

As a general trend, any instruction that's in widespread use in existing binaries will motivate CPU designers to make it fast.  For example, Pentium 4 tried to get everyone to stop using INC/DEC; that didn't work; [current CPUs do partial-flag renaming better than ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter).  Modern x86 transistor and power budgets can support that kind of complexity, at least for the big-core CPUs (not Atom / Silvermont).  Unfortunately I don't think there's any hope in sight for the false dependencies (on the destination) for instructions like `sqrtss` or `cvtsi2ss`, though.

---

Using the stack pointer explicitly in an instruction like `add rsp, 8` requires the stack engine in Intel CPUs to insert a sync uop to update the out-of-order back-end's value of the register.  Same if the internal offset gets too large.

In fact `pop dummy_register` is *more* efficient than `add rsp, 8` or `add esp,4` on modern CPUs, so compilers will typically use that to pop one stack slot with the default tuning, or with `-march=sandybridge` for example.  [Why does this function push RAX to the stack as the first operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773787/why-does-this-function-push-rax-to-the-stack-as-the-first-operation)

See also [What C/C++ compiler can use push pop instructions for creating local variables, instead of just increasing esp once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485395/what-c-c-compiler-can-use-push-pop-instructions-for-creating-local-variables) re: using `push` to initialize local variables on the stack instead of `sub rsp, n` / `mov`.  That could be a win in some cases, especially for code-size with small values, but compilers don't do it.

---

Also, no, GCC / clang won't make code that's *exactly* like what you show.

If they need to save registers around a function call, they will typically do that using `mov` to memory.  Or `mov` to a call-preserved register that they saved at the top of the function, and will restore at the end.

I've never seen GCC or clang push multiple call-clobbered registers before a function call, other than to pass stack args.  And definitely not multiple pops afterwards to restore into the same (or different) registers.  Spill/reload inside a function typically uses mov.  This avoids the possibility of push/pop inside a loop (except for passing stack args to a `call`), and allows the compiler to do branching without having to worry about matching pushes with pops.  Also it reduces complexity of stack-unwind metadata that has to have an entry for every instruction that moves RSP.  (Interesting tradeoff between instruction count vs. metadata and code size for using RBP as a traditional frame pointer.)

Something *like* your code-gen could be seen with call-preserved registers + some reg-reg moves in a tiny function that just called another function and then returned an `__int128` that was a function arg in registers.  So the incoming RSI:RDI would need to be saved, to return in RDX:RAX.

Or if you store to a global or through a pointer after a non-inline function call, the compiler would also need to save the function args until after the call.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and reference links!