# Is moving into another register faster or slower than push and pop?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel

For the purposes of storing and restoring a register, which one is faster?

Case 1:

```
mov  r9, rdi
mov  rdi, 10
call someFunction
mov  rdi, r9
```

Case 2:

```
push rdi
mov  rdi, 10
call someFunction
pop  rdi
```

Comment: Faster but you need a spare register.

Comment: Register-register moves are definitely cheaper than register-memory moves. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all

Comment: The call itself will probably take more time. You should consider inlining.

Comment: Inlining as in inline assembly?

Comment: Inlining in this context means that a function's body of code, or a relevant part of it, is inserted at the function call site instead of a `call` instruction and all the setup needed for it.

Comment: Inlining like what an optimizing compiler will do with a C function like `inline int foo(int x){ return x+1; }` - not actually `call` anything, just move that logic into the caller and optimize the whole thing.  If `someFunction` is short, it's good to do that by hand in asm.

Comment: Or change the function to an assembler macro.

Comment: If you have a helper function that you know doesn't touch `r9`, even though it's call-clobbered in the standard calling convention, that's perfect, 2x `mov reg,reg` is cheaper than `push`+`pop`.  Normally you'd need to pick a call-preserved register (like R12-R15, or RBX or RBP), which you'd push/pop at the start/end of your function.  That's definitely good if the call is inside a loop, or you have multiple calls in a function.  But if you have a tiny function that makes only one call, see [Why do compilers insist on using a callee-saved register here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61375336)