# How do callee-saved registers work? Who should push the original value onto the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, calling-convention

I'm learning **callee- and caller-saved registers** from CSAPP (Third Edition) on pg251, where I am aware that as for callee-saved registers:

> **Procedure Q (callee)** can preserve a register value by either not changing it at all or by **pushing** the original value on the stack, **altering** it, and then **popping** the old value from the stack before returning.

Additionally, I've learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers) post that:

> **Callee-saved registers** (AKA non-volatile registers, or call-preserved) are used to hold long-lived values that should be preserved across calls.

However, I am still confused when trying to understand an example in CSAPP (Third Edition) on pg252. The example is partially stated below:

```c
long P(long x, long y) {
    long u = Q(y); // The detail of Q is irrelevant here
    long v = Q(x);
    return u + v;
}
```

The corresponding assembly is generated by `gcc-11` as below:

```
_P:
LFB2:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI2:
    pushq   %rbx
LCFI3:
    subq    $8, %rsp
LCFI4:
    movq    %rdi, %rbp
    movq    %rsi, %rdi
    call    _Q
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    movq    %rbp, %rdi
    call    _Q
    addq    %rbx, %rax
    addq    $8, %rsp
LCFI5:
    popq    %rbx
LCFI6:
    popq    %rbp
LCFI7:
    ret
```

It is clear that %rbp and %rbx are **callee-saved registers**, and we could see that **procedure P (caller)** pushes %rbp and %rbx onto the stack.

- Does this mean that caller P (instead of callee Q) actually saves the values of the two registers?
- If so, does it contradict the role of callee-saved registers?

I would appreciate it if you could help me with the questions above. Thank you very much!

Comment: Keep in mind that `P` is _also_ a callee of some other function.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks! To be more specific, in this example where `P` calls `Q`, should we consider `P` as a callee or a caller?

Comment: @XuanChen P is both callee (of whoever called P) and caller (of Q).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that `P` is not only a *caller* but also a *callee*.

```
_P:
LFB2:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI2:
    pushq   %rbx
```

Here we can see that `P` saves `rbp` and `rbx` to save **its** *callers* values.

---

These two lines are interesting.

```
call    _Q
addq    %rbx, %rax
```

We can see that `P` calls `Q` and then adds `rbx` to its result (stored in `rax`). This implies `rbx` was not modified by `Q` which means `Q` must have preserved its value, i.e. it's *callee saved*.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that caller P (instead of callee Q) actually saves the values of the two registers?

These registers are saved by `P` for the benefit of `P`'s callers.  No function can use call-preserved registers without save & restore (unless this function never returns to its caller).

> If so, does it contradict the role of callee-saved registers?

No, it's necessary to follow the rules.

---

Since we don't see `Q`, we don't know what call-preserved registers it saves & restores — it only has to save call-preserved registers that it itself chooses to modify.  It might save & restore `rbp`, or both `rbp` and `rbx`, or neither, or even more.

Further, `Q` may call other functions, which may or may not use call-preserved registers — they are required to also preserve those registers' values.

---

Let's also note for fun that the above code could have used one less call-preserved register by rearranging the code just slightly.

The code (1) moves the return value/result of the first call to `Q` from `rax` into a into call-preserved register `rbx` (`u`), followed by (2) moving `x` (which was moved to `rbp`) into the parameter register `rdi` for the second call to `Q`.

By swapping the order of those two moves, the lifetimes of `u` and `x` will not overlap, and so could actually share the same storage location (e.g. a call-preserved register).

We would instead (1) move `x` (from `rbp`) into `rdi` for the second call, then (2) move `rax` into `rbp` — forgoing the need for two the call-preserved registers.

---

In another analysis, for the variables that are live across a call, I would have moved them onto the stack instead of using call-preserved registers.  This is because neither `x` nor `u` (the two variables that are live across a call) have any significant usage — each is read only once.

```
_P:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, (%rsp)          # one memory write
    movq    %rsi, %rdi
    call    _Q
    movq    (%rsp), %rdi          # one memory read
    movq    %rax, (%rsp)          # one memory write
    call    _Q
    addq    (%rsp), %rax          # one memory read
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

For a total of 10 instructions, with 2 writes and 2 reads to stack memory.

By comparison, the call-preserved register-using version you're showing above uses a total of 14 instructions, also with 2 writes and 2 reads to stack memory.

Now, if the body of the function `P` had a loop, then the call-preserved register using version could have a lower dynamic read & write count than the alternative that doesn't use call-preserved registers (probably: assuming the loop iterates more than once).

Comment: Related to your last section about spilling your own temporaries and register args yourself instead of saving/restoring call-preserved regs: [Why do compilers insist on using a callee-saved register here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61375336) - more instructions, but there's a chance critical-path latency is lower.  And that this strategy works better for larger functions where the same value is needed after multiple calls, or with loops, so it might just be compilers not special-casing very short functions (which should get inlined whenever possible anyway!)