# Why do we use sub esp, 4 instead of push a register in assembly?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86, stack, cpu-registers

If we use

```
push ecx
```

we should use one byte in the opcode, if we use

```
sub esp, 4
```

I think we should use 2 bytes? I've tried to read [the documentation](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_308.html) but I didn't understand much.
The reason is the same as in

```
xor eax, eax
```

instead of

```
mov eax, 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL:DR: Clang already does this.  GCC doesn't except at `-Os`.  I haven't benchmarked.

---

**Code-size isn't everything.  A dummy push is still a real store that takes up a store-buffer entry until it commits to cache.**  In fact code-size is usually the last thing to worry about, only when all else is equal (number of front-end uops, avoiding back-end bottlenecks, avoiding any performance pitfalls).

Historically (16-bit x86 before CPUs had caches), `push cx` would probably not have been faster than `sub sp, 2` (3 bytes) or `dec sp` / `dec sp` (2 bytes) on those old CPUs where memory bandwidth was the main factor in performance (including for code-fetch).  Optimizing for speed on 8088 especially is approximately the same as optimizing for code size.

The reason `xor eax,eax` is still preferred is that later CPUs were able to make it still at least as fast even apart from the code-size advantage.  [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and)

---

**On later CPUs like PPro, `push` decoded to multiple uops** (to adjust ESP and separately to store).  So on those CPUs, despite the smaller code size, it costs more in the front-end.  Or on P5 Pentium (which didn't decode complex instructions into multiple uops), `push` stalled the pipeline temporarily and was often avoided by compilers even when the store-to-memory side effect was desired.

But finally, around Pentium-M, [CPUs got a "stack engine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture) that handles the ESP-update part of stack operations outside of the out-of-order back-end, making it single-uop and zero latency (for the dep chain through ESP).  As you can see from that link, the stack-sync uops that the stack engine has to insert sometimes do make `sub esp,4` cost more than `push`, if you weren't already going to reference `esp` directly in the back end before the next stack op. (like `call`)

IDK if it really would have been a good idea to start using dummy `push ecx` on CPUs that old, or if limited store-buffer sizes meant that it wasn't a good idea to use up execution resources on doing dummy stores, even to cache lines that were almost certainly hot (the top of the stack).

**But anyway, modern compilers *do* use this peephole optimization,** especially in 64-bit mode where needing to adjust the stack by only one push is common.  Modern CPUs have large store buffers.

```
void foo();

int bar() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Clang has been doing this for several years.  e.g. with current clang 10.0 -O3 (optimize for speed over size) [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'void+foo()%3B%0A%0Aint+bar()+%7B%0A++++foo()%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1000,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'0',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fomit-frame-pointer',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+10.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:57.309322033898304,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+10.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:42.690677966101696,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

```
bar():
        push    rax
        call    foo()
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

GCC does this at `-Os`, but not at `-O3` (I tried with `-march=skylake`, still chooses to use `sub`.)

It's less easy to construct a case where `sub esp,4` would be useful, but this works:

```
int bar() {
    volatile int arr[1]= {0};
    return 0;
}
```

clang10.0 -m32 -O3 -mtune=skylake

```
bar():                                # @bar()
        push    eax
        mov     dword ptr [esp], 0     # missed optimization for push 0
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     ecx
        ret
```

Unfortunately compiler's don't spot the fact that `push 0` could have both initialized and reserved space for the `volatile int` object, replacing both `push eax` and `mov dword [esp], 0`  [What C/C++ compiler can use push pop instructions for creating local variables, instead of just increasing esp once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485395/what-c-c-compiler-can-use-push-pop-instructions-for-creating-local-variables)

Comment: I’m not sure that last example qualifies as  a missed optimization. I suspect their rules for volatile preclude combining them.

Comment: @prl: Fair, but I'm confident that if I was able to cook up a similar example without `volatile` we'd see the same push/mov. (perhaps with `-mprefered-stack-boundary=2` and passing a pointer to the local to a non-inline function.  Or an inline asm statement with a `"m"` input.)