# Why does push suffix only allow 2 and 8 byte values?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I've noticed that I'm only allowed to do `push` on an 8 byte or 2 byte value. For example:

```
push $5 # same as pushq
# sub  $8, %rsp
# movq $5,(%rsp)
```

Or:

```
pushw $3
# sub  $2, %rsp
# movw $3,(%rsp)
```

And making sure the stack looks correct with `gdb`:

```
>>> x/5hd $rsp
0x7fffffffe426: 3   5   0   0   0
```

However, all other suffixes give me:

> Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'

Why does `push` only allow using a 64 bit or 16 bit value? Is it common to use the `sub...mov` to be more specific, or is that an anti-pattern? Finally, does the CPU interpret `push` identical to a `sub...mov` instructions, or are they two different things entirely (that produce the same result) ?

Comment: `sub` modifies FLAGS but `sub+mov` is otherwise identical in its effect on architectural state.  I don't know exactly why the design decision was made *not* to let `REX.W=0` override the operand size from 64 to 32 in machine code, but that's why you can't encode a dword push in 64-bit mode.  See the linked duplicate.

Comment: It's not an anti-pattern to reserve *multiple* qwords of space and use `mov` to write some of them, but it would be braindead to use multiple separate `sub rsp, 8` instructions mixed with mov stores.  See [What C/C++ compiler can use push pop instructions for creating local variables, instead of just increasing esp once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49485395) for the minor optimization of using push to allocate + init locals.