# CSAPP: Why use subq followed by movq when we have pushq already

Tags: c, assembly, x86

So I was reading chapter 3 of CSAPP (3.7.4 Local Storage on the Stack).

In Figure 3.31, there is this snippet of code:

```c
long caller() {
    long arg1 = 534;
    long arg2 = 1057;
    long sum = swap_add(&arg1, &arg2);
    long diff = arg1 - arg2;
    return sum * diff;
}
```

and its generated assembly:

```
caller:
  subq    $16, %rsp
  movq    $534, (%rsp)
  movq    $1057, 8(%rsp)
  leaq    8(%rsp), %rsi
  movq    %rsp, %rdi
  call    swap_add
  movq    (%rsp), %rdx
  subq    8(%rsp), %rdx
  imulq   %rdx, %rax
  addq    $16, %rsp
  ret
```

My question is that why not use `pushq $1057` then `pushq $534` here.

I'm also aware that if we want to allocate space for some variable and leave it uninitialized, we should decreament `$rsp` directly as here. But I can't relate this fact with my question here.

Comment: That's how compilers normally do things, but yes it's a missed optimization.  [What C/C++ compiler can use push pop instructions for creating local variables, instead of just increasing esp once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49485395).  Many CS:APP examples are *actual* compiler output, not hand-written asm.

Comment: Thanks for the link and this useful knowledge about CS:APP, @PeterCordes