# Nested loops in nasm

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, nested-loops, stack-memory

I wrote the following program in nasm on a Windows 10 64bit machine

```
extern _GetStdHandle@4
extern _WriteFile@20
extern _ReadFile@20
extern _ExitProcess@4

;ReadBufferSize
%define rbs 100

section .rodata
    w: dd 3
    h: dd 3
    text: db "abc", 10

section .data
    x: dd 4
    y: dd 4

section .bss
    stdout: resb 4
    stdin: resb 4
    readbuff: resb (rbs+2); allow for CR, LF
    bytecnt: resb 4

section .text
    _print:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        push 0
        lea eax, [ebp-4]
        push eax
        mov eax, [ebp+8]
        push dword [eax]
        push dword [ebp+12]
        push dword [stdout]
        call _WriteFile@20

        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret 8

    _read:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        push 0
        push dword [ebp+8]
        push rbs
        push dword [ebp+12]
        push dword [stdin]
        call _ReadFile@20
        sub dword [bytecnt], 2; remove CR and LF

        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret 8
    _draw:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        
        push dword [w]
        L1:
            push dword [h]
            L2:
                push text
                push x
                call _print
            dec dword [ebp-8]
            cmp dword [ebp-8], 0
            jg L2
        dec dword [ebp-4]
        cmp dword [ebp-4], 0
        jg L1

        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret

    global _main
    _main:
        push -11
        call _GetStdHandle@4 ;Get Stdout handle
        mov [stdout], eax

        push -10
        call _GetStdHandle@4 ;Get Stdin handle
        mov [stdin], eax
        
        call _draw

        push 0
        call _ExitProcess@4

        hlt
```

I would have cleaned it up, but this may affect something, so I won't (sorry). The `_draw` function should output "abc\n" 9 (3*3) (3 and 3, because `w` and `h` are 3) times on the screen, but it only gets outputed 5 times. As far as I have checked, the `_print` works as intended. Here's my build script if it helps:

```
@echo off
IF "%~2" EQU "" set f0rm4t=win32
IF "%~2" NEQ "" set f0rm4t=%~2
if exist %1.exe rm %1.exe
if exist %1.obj rm %1.obj
nasm -f %f0rm4t% %1.asm
if exist %1.exe goto run
if not exist %1.obj goto end
gcc %1.obj -o %1.exe
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto run
:run
%1.exe
echo ------------------------
if %errorlevel% EQU -1073741819 (
    echo exited with C0000005
    goto end
)
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    echo exited successfully
    goto end
)
echo exited with return value %errorlevel%
:end
```

I build using the `build filename` command, and it functions correctly.
I have checked my logic, and it seems fine, so it's something with the nested loop and I don't know what exactly.
Complete `build` command output:

```
C:\Users\User\files>build filename
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
------------------------
exited successfully

C:\Users\User\files>
```

If the loops were working properly, then it would be impossible to get the output 5 times, because it should be (repetitions of the outer one)*(repetitions of the inner one), but 5 is a prime number. I can not figure this out, so I leave it to this community. Have a great day and thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `_draw` function pushes but never pops, so the stack is full of garbage instead of the loop control variables you're imagining.

Comment: @ErikEidt: well, the loop control variables are referenced through `ebp`, so those are not effected by the pushes, but you're right that the pushes of `w` and `h` do not seem to serve any useful purpose here.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError , `w` and `h` are constants declared in `section .rodata`, and I do not want to use them for loop control variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time through the outer loop, `[ebp-8]` counts down to zero. The next two times through the outer loop, `[ebp-8]` is already zero (or less), so the inner loop only executes once. For a total of five calls to print.

Note that the subsequent executions of `push [h]` don't change `[ebp-8]`.
On the second iteration, it writes to `[ebp-12]` and on the third iteration it writes to `[ebp-16]`, because the stack pointer continues to grow downward with each push.

To fix this, I suggest:

1. Add `sub esp, 8` right after `mov ebp, esp`.
2. Change `push [w]` to `mov eax, [w]; mov [ebp-4], eax`.
3. Change `push [h]` to `mov eax, [h]; mov [ebp-8], eax`.

Comment: Note that the fix suggested here is based on minimizing changes to your program just to fix the problem. There are other changes I would suggest: Keep the loop counters in registers. Dec sets flags, so you can use jg or jnz immediately after dec without a  cmp instruction.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the beginning of @prl 's answer, I realised that, like they said, `[ebp-8]` gets decremented to 0 in the first iteration of the inner loop and the next `push [h]` pushes to `[ebp-12]`, so `[ebp-8]` remains at 0. So the first thing I tought of was just adding a `pop edx` (using edx as a junk register) after the jumps, like this:

```
    _draw:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        
        push dword [w]
        L1:
            push dword [h]
            L2:
                push text
                push x
                call _print
            dec dword [ebp-8]
            cmp dword [ebp-8], 0
            jg L2
            pop edx
        dec dword [ebp-4]
        cmp dword [ebp-4], 0
        jg L1
        pop edx

        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
```

this would clear the already zeroed variables of the stack and make room for the new ones, and it works.

But I think @prl 's answer is more applicable in general for a technique for allocating variables on the stack, so if you can, use it, as it is alslo less confusing.

Comment: See also [What C/C++ compiler can use push pop instructions for creating local variables, instead of just increasing esp once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49485395) - it's slightly less efficient to use repeated push/pop than `mov edx, [h]` / `mov [ebp-8], edx`.   `push mem` decodes to 2 fused-domain uops on modern CPUs like Skylake and Zen (same as separate load and store insns), and using it means you need to balance it with `pop`.  This is actually good for code-size, though.  Of course, still makes more sense to save/restore e.g. EBX and EDI for use as counters, and `dec ebx / jg L2`