# Why EAX register is user as intermediary?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
(gdb) disass p
Dump of assembler code for function p:
   0x080484d4 <+0>:    push   ebp
   0x080484d5 <+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x080484d7 <+3>:    sub    esp,0x68
   0x080484da <+6>:    mov    eax,ds:0x8049860      <---
   0x080484df <+11>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax   <---

   ...

   0x0804853d <+105>:  leave
   0x0804853e <+106>:  ret
```

I want to understand something about the two lines denoted with arrows in the code above.

I know the first `mov` instruction moves the address `ds:0x8049860` into the register `eax`, and then in the second line we `mov` the content of `eax` (*I suppose it contains an address at this point*) into the 32-bits memory pointed with `esp`. (*I hope this is correct, please correct me if I'm wrong*).

What I dont understand is why we need the register `eax` as an intermediary between the two instructions?

Would it be possible if we replaced the two instructions with something like
`mov DWORD PTR [esp], ds:0x8049860`?

Comment: The `mov eax,ds:0x8049860` is a memory read (somewhat confusing disassembly). In more usual intel syntax that would look like `mov eax, [0x8049860]`. `mov` can not have 2 memory operands so you need the temporary.

Comment: When you say a memory read, does this mean the content of ```ds:0x8049860``` is moved to eax?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I want to ask the ```DWORD PTR [esp]``` thingy, is it used for derefrencing the esp?

Comment: It's somewhat of a missed optimization; a compiler could have used `push dword ptr [0x8049860]` (after subtracting only 4 instead of 8 from the stack pointer beforehand); see [What C/C++ compiler can use push pop instructions for creating local variables, instead of just increasing esp once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49485395) (and the linked duplicates at the top of the page for why `mov` from mem to mem isn't encodeable in x86 machine code)