# Why does disassembly show me push/pop to same register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have disassembled a C file.
At the start of what used to be a function I see

```
endbr64
push     %rax
pop      %rax
```

as the first instructions.

Why is the content of *%rax* pushed and then popped without any changes to the stack or the register in between? I would expect *%rax* to be unchanged by that operation.

Comment: `rax` is indeed unchanged by that operation. Could be either trash by an unoptimized build, not code at all interpreted as such, or more subtly a way to set the top of stack entry to the value of `rax`.

Comment: I assume that's the top of a function, given the `endbr64`.  What compiler / obfuscator / weird human generated the machine code you're disassembling?  I don't know any reason why you'd want to do this as a compact way to store RAX to `[rsp-8]`, which is the only net side-effect. of this, assuming no other threads or breakpoints are changing things asynchronously.  ([rsp-8] is in the red-zone below RSP on x86-64 SysV, but that's not a thing on Windows x64).  It's not something I've seen even in debug builds from mainstream compilers (GCC/clang/MSVC/ICC).

Comment: @Peter, possibly `int f() { int x; return x; }` ?   ...  although he did say "as the first instructions", implying that more follows.

Comment: @prl: No compiler I'm aware of knows how to initialize local vars with `push`.  Maybe this is for 16-byte stack alignment around an empty function body?

Comment: @Peter sadly, I don't have the compile script available, because the binary is from a security class I'm taking where it is about exploiting the program. The only thing I know is that the code is compiled using gcc with symbols, has partial RELRO and no PIE

Comment: I'm really surprised to see this in GCC output.  I wouldn't expect that in GCC output unless the source used nline asm to put it there.  What is the surrounding code?  You're not maybe disassembling data that wasn't supposed to be code?

Comment: Apparently, it is due to the "-fstack-clash-protection" flag in GCC (see https://godbolt.org/z/Pvd1ox9d3). It is removed, however, if the call to exit() is removed as well

Comment: @Venturion Consider posting your last comment as an answer.

Comment: @Peter, coincidentally, this answer has an example of clang allocating an uninitialized variable using push. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73984434/8422330

Comment: @prl: Allocating / deallocating space with dummy push/pop, yes that's a well known thing.  I said *initializing*, which is a [missed optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485395/what-c-c-compiler-can-use-push-pop-instructions-for-creating-local-variables) when GCC/clang do `push rcx` / `mov [rsp], edi` instead of `push rdi`.  (Although since your C example didn't init, only read, I should have said *reading*.)  In that linked Q&A, note that it's a silly `mov al, [rsp]` / `pop rcx`, not `pop rax`.

Comment: @Peter, so your previous response was a nonsequitur, then, since my example clearly showed an uninitialized variable?

Comment: @prl: Agreed. The correct rebuttal is that compilers miss the optimization of using `pop` to load a variable and free its space at the end of a function.  That's highly related to knowing how to allocate + init a variable with `push`, but a separate optimization.  (Some compilers will decide the value of a C variable that's read uninitialized, e.g. sometimes forcing it to 0 instead of reading garbage from a register.  But I mixed up some ideas like thinking about the compiler picking some garbage register to init with, or AL= # of XMM args, so the push could be an init.. But that's unlikely.)

Comment: I don't get why the compiler gets this wrong. Why doesn't it understand that the registers and flags are the same before and after?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it is due to the "-fstack-clash-protection" flag in GCC (see [godbolt.org/z/Pvd1ox9d3](https://godbolt.org/z/Pvd1ox9d3)). It is removed, however, if the call to exit() is removed.

In case the link goes down: The following code is compiled there with *x86-64 gcc 12.2* using the flags
"-fstack-clash-protection -O1":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void fun(void) {
    printf("hello\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Seems like a missed optimization, then.  `push/pop/sub rsp,8` is super dumb when it could just do like clang (with some `-march=` settings) and use one `push` *instead* of `sub rsp,8` to align the stack for a call as well as touching it.  https://godbolt.org/z/hd99v88T7 .  It's a missed optimization anyway because `call` pushes a return address and `sub rsp,8` is less than 4096, so it can't skip a single guard page.

Comment: But yes, it seems you've correctly identified where this nonsense is coming from.