# Is returning an empty class in C++ is the same as returning nothing (void)?

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization

I was wondering if it's the same in terms of end-case performance if I return an empty, member-less class/struct versus returning nothing (as in a `void`-declared function).

```
struct nothing {};

void func1()
{
};

nothing func2()
{
     return nothing{};
};

int main()
{
    func1();
    nothing n = func2();
}
```

Will those calls to `func1` and `func2` actually produce the same assembly output on modern compilers?

I'm specifically interested in an `inline`-rich header-only code to be behaving the same as a void-yielding counterpart. I'm also fine if those two are coming close in an optimized compilation build.

Comment: "Will those calls to func1 and func2 actually produce the same assembly output on modern compilers?" - just use http://godbolt.org/ to check.

Comment: Any type besides `void` would need some in memory instance of at least one byte in some circumstances, so I won't expect that your `struct nothing` could serve as a replacement for `void`.

Comment: There's a [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) provided in the standard C++ library, which is a well-behaved empty class.  (You can read up why `struct nothing {};` may not be as well behaved as you'd like.)

Answer (score 3):

So, I'm investigating this on clang 14.0.6 with a command like so:

```
clang++ -O0 -S -masm=intel test.cpp
```

The `func1` results in:

```
    .globl  "?func1@@YAXXZ"                 # -- Begin function ?func1@@YAXXZ
    .p2align    4, 0x90
"?func1@@YAXXZ":                        # @"?func1@@YAXXZ"
# %bb.0:
    ret
                                        # -- End function
```

While `func2` results in:

```
    .globl  "?func2@@YA?AUnothing@@XZ"      # -- Begin function ?func2@@YA?AUnothing@@XZ
    .p2align    4, 0x90
"?func2@@YA?AUnothing@@XZ":             # @"?func2@@YA?AUnothing@@XZ"
.seh_proc "?func2@@YA?AUnothing@@XZ"
# %bb.0:
    push    rax
    .seh_stackalloc 8
    .seh_endprologue
    mov al, byte ptr [rsp]
    pop rcx
    ret
    .seh_endproc
                                        # -- End function
```

The main is looking as such (see the commented line):

```
main:                                   # @main
.seh_proc main
# %bb.0:
    sub rsp, 40
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    call    "?func1@@YAXXZ"
    call    "?func2@@YA?AUnothing@@XZ"
    mov byte ptr [rsp + 32], al         # -- This line is also a cost of 'nothing'
    xor eax, eax
    add rsp, 40
    ret
    .seh_endproc
                                        # -- End function
```

We can actually see the difference here that is somewhat expected since empty structs/classes are actually 1-byte in length in C++, also possibly needing an additional debug-time instruction to step.

It's however important to see if this would be properly optimized out, so continuing with:

```
clang++ -O1 -S -masm=intel test.cpp
```

This time the functions look identical:

```
    .globl  "?func1@@YAXXZ"                 # -- Begin function ?func1@@YAXXZ
    .p2align    4, 0x90
"?func1@@YAXXZ":                        # @"?func1@@YAXXZ"
# %bb.0:
    ret
                                        # -- End function

    .globl  "?func2@@YA?AUnothing@@XZ"      # -- Begin function ?func2@@YA?AUnothing@@XZ
    .p2align    4, 0x90
"?func2@@YA?AUnothing@@XZ":             # @"?func2@@YA?AUnothing@@XZ"
# %bb.0:
    ret
                                        # -- End function
```

The `main` gets obviously flushed out due to no meaningful side-effects of the calls:

```
main:                                   # @main
# %bb.0:
    xor eax, eax
    ret
                                        # -- End function
```

We could obviously add those with some more intricate logic, but for this time, I'm satisfied with the results which are within my current problematic scope, i.e., for a simple inline-visible scope returning nothing is identical to 'returning' void.

Comment: "In terms of performance" from the question indeed is not answered at all by `-O0`.

Comment: You have shown that unused variables in main get optimized away. That happens even for more complicated, non-empty classes.

Comment: @BoP well, yes and no, since the -O1 generated code for the routines alone is becoming  essentially identical. The main's reduction is obvious though, but it's still interesting in how empty class can't actually be ever used (i.e. has no fields), hence I think that's why the -O1 did it to func2's body making it the same as func1's.

Comment: Use -O2 or -O3 to get more meaningful results.  If the compiler takes too much out, then  remove the opportunities it has to inline by compiling only one function at a time.